# Chow-Robbins Game: Optimal Decision Stopping vs Continuing, threshold

Tags: probability-theory

I have a question concerning the so-called Chow-Robbins Game, where a coin is tossed repeatedly and a player can stop whenever he wants. Then he receives a payoff equal to the proportion of heads.
For the player, it is optimal to stop if the expected payoff while continuing is less than the payoff guaranteed in the current position. 
I refer to the paper "Rigorous computer analysis of the Chow-Robbins game" by Wästlund and Häggström (arxiv.org/pdf/1201.0626v1.pdf). That's why I use their notation (a,n) for the position with a heads out of n total coin flips. Then a-(n-a)=2a-n is the difference between number of heads and tails in a given position.

Until now, I have failed to prove a statement which is stated at the beginning of the fourth part of the paper. There it says that if stopping is optimal in a given position (a,n), then this holds for any other position (b,m) with 2b-m=2a-n and m less than n, too.
The statement somehow seems to be very obvious, but hard to prove rigorously. In the paper it says that it is easy to prove it by a coupling argument, but I have been unable to get that.

Thanks in advance for your help!